# Docker exec quoting variables

Tags: bash, docker, escaping, dockerfile

I'd like to know if there's a way to do this

Let's say the `dockerfile` contains this line, that specifies path of an executable

`ENV CLI /usr/local/bin/myprogram`

I'd like to be able to call this program using ENV variable name through `exec` command.

For example
`docker exec -it <my container> 'echo something-${CLI}`
Expecting 
`something-/usr/local/bin/myprogram`

However that returns:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"${CLI} do something\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do it, all you need to do is evaluate command with bash

`docker exec -it <container id> bash -c 'echo something-${CLI}'`

returns `something-/usr/local/bin/myprogram`

If the `CLI` environment variable is not already set in the container, you can also pass it in such as:

`docker exec -it -e CLI=/usr/local/bin/myprogram <container id> bash -c 'echo something-${CLI}'`

See the help file:

```
 docker exec --help

 Usage: docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

 Run a command in a running container

Options:
-d, --detach               Detached mode: run command in the background
-e, --env list             Set environment variables
....
```

Comment: I stand by my statement that I question your ability to understand even your own answer. Your original request (before your edits) was `docker exec -it <my container> '${CLI} do something'`, this will not work, usage: `docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]`, "`COMMAND` should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will not work" (ref. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

Comment: @masseyb well you haven't understood the question then

Comment: keep telling yourself that. 1 edit that only changes the expected results, I mean for sure, everyone should be able to guess what you’re actually expecting amirite. Also, love the double standard, « the proper answer is x because ... <explanation> ». How about providing an explanation for your answer?

Comment: Is it possible without additional shell?

Answer (score -3):

In it's [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54450351/1) `docker exec -it <my container> '${CLI} do something'` with the expectation that `${CLI}` will be substituted with `/usr/local/bin/myprogram` (as the `exec COMMAND`) and everything after passed as `ARG`'s to `/usr/local/bin/myprogram` will not work, this is clearly documented: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

> `COMMAND` should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will not work. Example:
>
> `docker exec -ti my_container "echo a && echo b"` will not work, but
>
> `docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a && echo b"` will.

Following the documentation, this will work as expected: `docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "${CLI} foo"`, `${CLI}` will be be executed after variable expansion and the argument(s) passed to the shell script set in `${CLI}` (e.g. `sh -c /usr/local/bin/myprogram foo`).

Alternatively you could set the `ENTRYPOINT` to your script and pass in arguments with `CMD` or at the command line with `docker run` for example:

Given the below directory structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── example.sh
```

The `Dockerfile` contents:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY example.sh /bin
RUN chmod u+x /bin/example.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/example.sh"]
CMD ["bla"]
```

And the `example.sh` script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

The `CMD` specified in the `Dockerfile` after the `ENTRYPOINT` will be the default argument for your script and you can override the default argument on the command line (assuming that the image is built and tagged as `example:0.1`):

```
user@host> docker run --rm example:0.1
bla
user@host> docker run --rm example:0.1 "arbitrary text"
arbitrary text
```

**Note**: this is my go to article for differences between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in `Dockerfile`'s: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my question, as your proposed solution has no relevance

Comment: @Ben my answer to your question of ~"if it's possible" is no, I don't believe so on the basis that the environment variables specified after the `docker exec` command appear to be evaluated on the host, e.g. `export CLI=random` on your host then `docker exec -it <your_container> ${CLI} do something` without quotes will substitute `${CLI}` with the value set on the host (if set in your environment - error: `... process caused "exec: \"random\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`), not in the container and with quotes the variable is not substituted at all hence your error.

Comment: Yes, a simple 'no' should be enough, however your proposal with *ENTRYPOINT* truly has no relevance. I did not asked how to set an executable, all I wanted to do is quoting container local variables in exec context. `docker exec -it <my container> 'echo ${CLI}'` for example

Comment: @Ben I answered your question in the first line, ignore everything after that if you want, same diff.

Comment: `I don't believe it's going to be possible` can not be considered as an answer. It implies that you're not sure. The proper answer is `No, because ... <explanation>`

Comment: @Ben take it or leave it, don't care, test it yourself maybe. Answer your own question if you're absolutely certain and move on guy. Maybe take the question to IRC #docker-dev they might be able to provide the "yes" or "no" absolute answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Ben in it's original format your answer is not the solution, "`COMMAND` should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will not work" (ref. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/): `docker exec -it <my container> '${CLI} do something'` <--- "quoted command will not work" is your absolute answer straight from the official documentation.